# make - how to list googletest lib as dependency

Tags: gnu-make, googletest

I am able to build [googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/googletest/README.md) and use it to run unit tests.

In **MY** makefile for my `unit_test.cpp`, I need to check whether `googletest` libs exist in `..\googletest\` and only if they do not exist, I want to run cmake and make for `googletest`.

Running cmake and make even if they are built takes 30 secs so I only want to run cmake and make if I actually have to.

**QUESTION**

In **MY** makefile for my `unit_test.cpp`, what could I list as a dependency so that building `googletest` only happens if actually necessary?

A "brute force" approach would be to list `googletest\build\lib\libgtest.a` but this would break if, however unlikely, `googletest` changes the output name from `lib\` to `libs\`.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get the question. Makefile is generated by CMake, it handles all locations of dependencies. You should not list those locations. By the way, you can use the libraries as `GTest::gtest` and `GTest::gmock` in CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @273K In my makefile for my unit test, I may or may not need to build googletest i.e. run `cmake .. & make` so that `libgtest` is built. If `libgtest` is already built, I do not want to run `cmake .. & make` for googletest because that takes 30 seconds.

Comment: @273K in **MY** makefile for my `unit_test.cpp`, how do I determine whether I need to execute the googletest build commands?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about possible change of the file layout in the build directory, you can use `cmake --install` command and directly specify the subfolders for header files and libraries before running cmake configure step. `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable allows to specify install directory and `CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR`, `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` variables allow to specify subfolders for header files and libraries, accordingly:

```makefile
GOOGLETEST_SRC_DIR := googletest
GOOGLETEST_BUILD_CACHE_DIR := googletest_build_cache

GOOGLETEST_SDK_DIR := googletest_sdk
GOOGLETEST_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR := include
GOOGLETEST_SDK_LIB_DIR := lib

GOOGLETEST_LIB := gtest
GOOGLETEST_MAIN_LIB := $(GOOGLETEST_LIB)_main

UT := ut
UT_SRC := ut.cpp

default_target: $(UT)

$(GOOGLETEST_BUILD_CACHE_DIR) :
    cmake                                                       \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(shell pwd)/$(GOOGLETEST_SDK_DIR) \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=$(GOOGLETEST_SDK_LIB_DIR)          \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR=$(GOOGLETEST_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR)  \
      -B $(GOOGLETEST_BUILD_CACHE_DIR) -S $(GOOGLETEST_SRC_DIR)
    cmake --build $(GOOGLETEST_BUILD_CACHE_DIR) --parallel
    touch $(GOOGLETEST_BUILD_CACHE_DIR)

$(GOOGLETEST_SDK_DIR): $(GOOGLETEST_BUILD_CACHE_DIR)
    cmake --install $(GOOGLETEST_BUILD_CACHE_DIR)
    touch $(GOOGLETEST_SDK_DIR)

$(UT): $(UT_SRC) $(GOOGLETEST_SDK_DIR)
    g++ $(UT_SRC) -o $(UT)                                  \
      -I$(GOOGLETEST_SDK_DIR)/$(GOOGLETEST_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR) \
      -L$(GOOGLETEST_SDK_DIR)/$(GOOGLETEST_SDK_LIB_DIR)     \
      -l$(GOOGLETEST_MAIN_LIB) -l$(GOOGLETEST_LIB)

clean:
    rm -f $(UT)
    rm -fR $(GOOGLETEST_BUILD_CACHE_DIR) $(GOOGLETEST_SDK_DIR)
```